# Error in MySQL : field list is ambiguous but not able to get the reason

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables vendors, components and catalog, here is the schema:

vendors - vid,vaddress,vname
components- cid, cname, type
catalog- cid, vid, cost

catalog is connected with the 2 tables with a foreign key vid and cid.

Query:

```
select vid
from catalog c,
     components com,
     vendors v
where com.cid = c.cid and c.vid = v.vid and v.vaddress = 'Noida'
   or c.cname = 'antenna';
```

> ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'vid' in field list is ambiguous.

I am getting this error.

Comment: Change select vid to select c.vid .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `c.vid`. Even when they are the same by the condition, you need to specivy which value you want to select, since just `vid` could be eigther `c.vid` or `v.vid`

Comment: `You need to select c.vid` ... no, selecting `v.vid` would also be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Both the `components` and `vendors` tables have a `vid` column, so selecting `vid` without a scoping alias or table name is ambiguous because it is not clear *which* table you are referring to.  On top of this, you should be using modern explicit joins.  Consider this version:

```sql
SELECT v.vid
FROM catalog c
INNER JOIN components com ON com.cid = c.cid
INNER JOIN vendors v ON c.vid = v.vid
WHERE v.vaddress = 'Noida' OR c.cname = 'antenna';
```